# Spring Boot with Elasticsearch embedded conflicting on port 54022

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to start two spring-boot (1.3.2.RELEASE) app instances on my dev machine. The app uses elasticsearch embedded (1.5.2) through spring data elasticsearch (1.3.2.RELEASE).

I configured instances to use different ports (`-Dserver.port=8081`), and this works well for my other app without elasticsearch.

So, my first instance starts normally, with second instance start I'm getting

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 54022; nested exception is: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I've tried to get more info from the logs, but it didn't help.

```
logging.level.org.elasticsearch=TRACE
```

I even tried

```
logging.level.root=TRACE
```

No mention about the port 54022. Google doesn't help much either.

**Update:** I start my instances in STS. When shutting down the instance (red square button in the console view) I see that STS connects to 54022 port. Maybe it's some kind of shutdown port?

`andrey:~$ lsof -i tcp:54022
STS     447 andrey   36u  IPv6 0xf4ba94cfea1e25e5      0t0  TCP localhost:49424->localhost:54022 (CLOSE_WAIT)`

Comment: You can check the application PID using the port 54022 with the command `sudo netstat -nap | grep 54022`

Comment: My first instance of two gets the 54022 and the second cannot start, giving the "Port already in use" error. I can see it from (netstat -p does not work in my terminal)

`$ lsof -i tcp:54022`

Comment: Do you use the embedded server of Spring Boot or an external applications server ? `-Dserver.port=8081` will only work for the embedded one.

Comment: Embedded in spring boot app. One JVM per instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is specific to STS IDE (Spring Tool Suite). This is not reproducible if you run the app from console.

54022 is `JMX Port` by STS.

To solve the issue go to `Run > Run Configurations... > Spring Boot App > <your_run_config> > Spring Boot (Tab)`.

Toggle `Enable Live Bean` support or change the `JMX Port`.